# Modern Mathematical Theory for Neural Networks, Cellular Automata, Neuroscience

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence, cellular-automata

Is it possible for someone to do research on subjects like neural networks, cellular automata, or neuroscience as an applied mathematician?

I have in mind the theoretical development of these fields, especially utilizing modern mathematics, e.g. algebraic geometry, differential operators, Lie groups, category theory...

Comment: There's a postgraduate program in cognitive science at my university that accepts people from psychology, neuroscience, biology, linguistics, philosophy, antropology, computer science (namely **AI**) and **mathematics**.

Comment: Very interesting question. Theoretical developments in deep learning could come from many different fields, in general from learning theory, statistics, and optimization theories, etc. I am not qualified to make such predictions but I like the question.

Comment: @Memming Thanks a lot for your advice, since in the future after current applied math-cs bachelor, I'm really excited to be involved in Computational Neuroscience from mathematical aspect. Recently, I want to try to finish bachelor thesis based on Computational Neuroscience or Neural Networks mathematically to be a starting point.

Comment: @ask Cool! I have been doing research in computational neuroscience and machine learning for a while. Statistics and optimization are really important, so make sure you master those. :)